# How to get the filenumber that is being processing by an awk script?

Tags: awk

Suppose I have 2 or more files being processed by an **awk** script.

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c

$ cat file2
d
e
```

How do I get the number of the file being processed? Is the a built-in **awk** for that?

I want to have a script with the behavior of the one bellow. What could I use as my 
`SOMEVARIABLE`?

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME, NR, FNR, SOMEVARIABLE, $0}' file1 file2
file1 1 1 1 a
file1 2 2 1 b
file1 3 3 1 c
file2 4 1 2 d
file2 5 2 2 e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP needs output in a specific format and DO NOT want only count of file so adding following solution now, which should consider empty files count too.(tested and written in GNU `awk`)

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  FNUM++
}
{
  print FILENAME, NR, FNR, FNUM, $0
}
ENDFILE{
  if(FNUM==prev){
    FNUM++
    print FILENAME, 0, 0, FNUM, "Empty file"
  }
prev=FNUM
}' file1 file2
```

Output for 1 Input_file1 and empty Input_file2 comes as follows.

```
file1 1 1 1 a
file1 2 2 1 b
file1 3 3 1 c
file2 0 0 2 Empty file
```

---

---

---

***Solutions when one wants to know total number of files processed by `awk` command:***

***1st solution:*** Could you  please try following, using GNU `awk`(considering that you don't want to count empty files here).

```
awk 'NF{count++;nextfile} END{print count}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you only want to know number of files passed to `awk` command then try following.

```
awk 'END {print ARGC-1}' Input_file1 Input_file2
```

***Explanation of above codes above  with examples:*** Let's say following are the Input_files, where Input_file1 is  having contents and Input_file2 is empty file as follows:

```
cat Input_file1
a
b
c
> Input_file2
```

Now when we run command `ARGC` we get output as 2 files.

```
awk 'END {print ARGC-1}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
2
```

Now when I run my 1st command it gives 1 file since it is not counting empty file.

```
awk 'NF{count++;nextfile} END{print count}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... I managed to do it as following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FNUM=0} FNR==1{FNUM++} {print FILENAME, NR, FNR, FNUM, $0}' file1 file2
file1 1 1 1 a
file1 2 2 1 b
file1 3 3 1 c
file2 4 1 2 d
file2 5 2 2 e
```

I guess there is no built-in variable to help with that, so I created the variable `FNUM` (for file number). If there is a solution with a built-in variable, please give me a better answer.

Comment: You could club this with mine 1st solution. Let me post it now. That is making sure that no empty file is being counted.

Comment: `BEGIN{FNUM=0}`  is not needed.

Comment: Note also that empty files won't be counted since `FNR==1` won't be satisfied.

Comment: @LEo, Could you please check my EDIT solution once, it handles empty files too, let me know?

Comment: @karakfa, Sir how about my EDIT solution, your views.

Comment: Your solution is as good as any I'd say. As noted you're going to fail to count empty files this way (files where `FNR` is never set to `1`), and your `BEGIN` is not needed (awk variables pre-init to `0`/`""`). If you have gnu awk and the empty-file issue is of concern, you might want to use `BEGINFILE{++FNUM}` instead, but it's a "non-standard" feature if portability is a concern.

Comment: @Jeff Y, I have used ENDFILE with checking of variable with prev variable, you could check it once.