# Replace each 2 nth occurs from a string in separate files using line range from another file

Tags: awk, stdout, stdin, gsub, tee

I have three files:

`0.txt` e `0-1.txt` with same content bellow:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree(home_cool)\t",
```

and source file `1.txt` below:

```
(food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,)
(sky, cat,)(sun, sea,)
(car, shape)(milk, market,)
(man, shirt)(hair, life)
(dog, big)(bal, pink)
```

For `0.txt` I would like to replace every *2 nth* occurs from `home_cool` by *1 nth* `1.txt` line, but only using only up to the second line of `1.txt` (then `sed -n '1,2p'`), such that my `2.txt` output is as below:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
```

When finishing the process at `2.txt`, I would like to replace all *2 nth* occurring from `home_cool` at `0-1.txt` by *1 nth* `1.txt` line using the third line of `1.txt` onwards (then `sed -n '3,5p'`), such that my `3.txt` output is as below:

```
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
```

With the line below I can separate into two steps the replacement of `home_cool` at `0.txt` (first step `sed -n '1,2p'` and second step `sed -n '3,5p'`). But I would like to save the first step in `2.txt` and the second step in `3.txt`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; n=NR; next}/home_cool/ { gsub("home_cool", a[int((++i-1)%(n*2)/2)+1])}1' <(cat 1.txt | tee >(sed -n '1,2p') >(sed -n '3,5p')) 0.txt >> 2.txt
```

so what I really wanted was something like (pseudocode below):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; n=NR; next}/home_cool/ { gsub("home_cool", a[int((++i-1)%(n*2)/2)+1])}1' <(cat 1.txt | tee >(sed -n '1,2p') >(sed -n '3,5p')) | "to sed -n '1,2p' make" 0.txt >> 2.txt | "to sed -n '3,5p' make" 0-1.txt >> 3.txt
```

How could I do this by maintaining a command line without breaking in several awk fragments isolated?

Note: perhaps the title of the question should be "multiple inputs, same process, different outputs"

Comment: Related, I assume: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69867423/4162356 Are _2 nth_ and _1 nth_ 2nd and 1st?

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes, related, but not enough I believe for this new question.

Comment: @Cyrus I thinks that may be unfair. Did they actually delete a question with answers? I only saw that they deleted one question - a previous version of this one, because it was hard to articulate the problem clearly. Let alone for someone who (apparently) has english as a second language. The problem is described more clearly in this version. OP should have edited their previous question, instead of deleting and reposting, and maybe had it reviewed by a coworker or friend first.

Comment: @dan I agree with Cyrus, what happens is that I have already deleted the old question, the most correct is to keep this new question and if I need to edit it completely if necessary.

Comment: @dan: Someone deleted my comment. An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69788918/repeat-nth-number-until-the-nth-match-while-appending-in-different-contexts-us) for a question with answer.

Comment: It's going to be hard to program this: you have 2 separate algorithms to generate 2.txt and 3.txt.

Comment: @Cyrus I see no answer in this old question deleted, and as far as I know I can not delete questions already answered, what was there in this case is who someone answered but deleted their own answer and then I thought it better to delete it

Comment: @glennjackman I believe it will be necessary to store the outputs in variables, and maybe use `tee`, but so far I have not had a great progress

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm: In this case, the answer was deleted by the author after a comment from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
awk \
'FNR==1 {++f}
f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(j++/2)%2]) }; print > "2.txt"}
f==3 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2]) }; print > "3.txt"}' \
    1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt
```

Alternatives to hardcoding `"2.txt"` and `"3.txt"` include:

- Use variables assigned with `-v outfile1=2.txt -v outfile2=2.txt`
- Replace them with `outfile`, and use this arg list: `1.txt outfile=2.txt 0.txt outfile=3.txt 0-1.txt`
- Replace them with `ARGV[4]` and `ARGV[5]`, add the line `f==4 {exit}`, and use this arg list: `1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`

Caveats:

- If a given file is empty, it will not cause `f` to increment, and break things accordingly. In gawk, `ENDFILE` can be used instead. See this answer: [How to get the filenumber that is being processing by an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015719/how-to-get-the-filenumber-that-is-being-processing-by-an-awk-script)

Comment: It worked exactly as expected, I will be reading the documentation with your response. Thank you very much to the user markp-fuso. I really will be avoiding deleting questions, I often think they do not have any resources to be answered and I end up deleting it to have a time and renew my thoughts. Thanks user Cyrus also, as others users by council.

Comment: maybe this is a conversation for a chat but I'm trying to put a shell command via `system()` inside `awk` before `f==3` print `3.txt`, the only issue is that the shell command is coming in loop and being repeated, should I open a new question?

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm You can put `if (FNR==1) {system("#")}` as the first command inside the `f==3` block.

Comment: I did testing and it worked, even when I add second shell command waiting before a third replacement process with the new output `4.txt`. look here https://onlinegdb.com/brgArNpwF. If you wish to answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877886/run-shell-command-inside-awk-only-once-using-system .

Comment: see `3.sh` https://onlinegdb.com/brgArNpwF

Comment: Could you explain better about the use of number of total rows of the `1.txt` file, and about `array indides` used in this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to OP's [previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69867423) ...

While it's certainly possible we could modify the (accepted answer to the) previous Q&A to perform these split operations across the various inputs, I'd vote for simplicity over complexity by breaking this new question into two separate operations, eg:

```
awk '... from previous Q&A ...' <(head -2 1.txt) 0.txt   > 2.txt
awk '... from previous Q&A ...' <(tail +3 1.txt) 0-1.txt > 3.txt
```

Stripping out the unnecessary `/house_cool01/{...}` line of code this becomes:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; n=NR; next} /home_cool/ {gsub("home_cool", a[int((i++)%(n*2)/2)+1] )} 1' <(head -2 1.txt) 0.txt   > 2.txt
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0; n=NR; next} /home_cool/ {gsub("home_cool", a[int((i++)%(n*2)/2)+1] )} 1' <(tail +3 1.txt) 0-1.txt > 3.txt
```

These generate:

```
$ cat 2.txt
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((food, apple,)(bag, tortoise,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((sky, cat,)(sun, sea,))\t",

$ cat 3.txt
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((man, shirt)(hair, life))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"#sun\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((dog, big)(bal, pink))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
"machine(shoes_shirt.shop)\t",
"car_snif = house.group_tree((car, shape)(milk, market,))\t",
```

Comment: but this fragments into several blocks of awk, exactly what I do not seek

Comment: relatively clean/simple implementation; easier to understand/maintain than an alternative/likely-convoluted solution; [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle); could you update the question to explain why you need a single `awk` call?

Comment: I'm trying to give a solution as well, meanwhile I try to make the issue clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I am schematizing everything I need to ask in the future to work with the maximum of simplicity, instead of presenting very fragmented problems of your real context.