# Run Shell Command Inside Awk only Once 'per command' Using System(), i e, print only Once "text"

Tags: awk, system

I have the following example of awk script below according to a prior answer to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874658/10824251:

```
awk \
'
FNR==1 {++f}

f==1 {a[i++]=$0}
f==2 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(j++/2)%2]) }; print > "2.txt"}
k==1 {system("echo 'text' && sleep 4")}
f==3 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2]) }; print > "3.txt"}
k==1 {system("echo 'text2' && sleep 4")}
f==4 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2]) }; print > "4.txt"}' \
    1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt 0-2.txt
```

I am trying to add a command shell only one time run after creating the `2.txt` file and before creating the `3.txt` file.

*This means that the specific shell command should only be executed after the `2.txt` file has been fully created.*

*The solution should also be able to print `text2` before `4.txt` to be created*.

I am using `system()`, my attempt so far it does not work well and the only thing that does not work is that the shell script is performed 3 times rather than 1 (this can be seen with the 3 `text` prints on the screen).

What can I do to see what really misses to solve this and `echo 'text'` is run only once and before `2.txt` be created?

I tried to insert a counter (without `whil`e) inside `system()` (`system("counter=0; if [[ "$counter" -gt 2 ]] then echo "text" fi; sleep 4")`) but did not work, and it really does not make much sense because `counter=0` should be out of `system()` I believe.

**Note to Clarify Choice of Answer with Solved Status :**

Doubt complex and cruel, choose which answer I will give as solved:

On the one hand the simplicity that explains a lot on the own account of the user @dan answer (author's answer to the previous issue of the file number in `awk`);

On the other hand a answer with a very useful deepening for learning from user @markp-fuso.

*Maybe I should think about other users when they need to read this issue, so I'll choose how solved the issue of markp-fuso. I hope to understand all the authors of answers to this issue.*

Comment: Just add a variable `haverun` and use `k==1 && haverun==0`. Then after `system("echo 'text' && sleep 4")` add `; haverun=1`. You can name it anything you like. You are just using the variable as a flag to tell you if `system()` has been run or not.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'll try this to understand better, I'll be back again, thank you for now.

Comment: Think of a flag is just being a `0`/ `1`, or `not run` / `run` way of keeping track of the "state" of whether `system()` has been run. You can use the same flag concept in programming in an endless number of ways. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am running your guidelines, just another time and I'll tell you if it worked

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not a specialist in `awk` and I think it's not declaring the variable `haverun` correctly, if you can please check this https://onlinegdb.com/sMSVzc83K.

Comment: Do this. `awk -v haverun=0 \ ...` or remove the variable there and before `FNR==1 {++f}` add `BEGIN { haverun=0 }`. Either way will work.

Comment: You can even eliminate the declaration completely. When awk encounters a variable not yet declared, it is defined to have a value of `0`. So if you look at my first comment, I don't mention declaring `haverun` anywhere. Example `printf "%s\n" a b 1 2 3 | awk 'haverun>1; { haverun++ }'` (**note:** a condition not followed by `{ .. }` like `haverun>1` simply uses the default command `print` -- if you are wondering how the numbers got printed) [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is your friend.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I corrected the declaration of the variable haverun, but I could not get this working because I believe that I am having difficulty in conjugating the use of the variable within the context of the code, I know something I'm doing wrong, I just do not know what it is, see here https://onlinegdb.com/2aokOTrAX.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin see `2.sh`  https://onlinegdb.com/2aokOTrAX

Comment: awk is a tool to manipulate text. A shell is a tool to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to other tools. You're trying to write an awk script that sequences calls to other tools, i.e. you're trying to make awk do the job that the shell exists to do. I strongly recommend you don't do that and just have shell call awk and other tools as appropriate. I wish your questions were clearer so we could direct you in how to do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way instead of helping you implement what is almost certainly the wrong way.

Comment: @EdMorton At this point I need to know the limit on which this can affect me the security limit that does not affect me, and maybe this is subjective for each person, it is necessary that I walk to a balance, but if you have lines of thought of how this question It can be resolved to be having no `awk` and `shell` usurpation and vice versa, I am ready for suggestions, thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what it is you're actually trying to do so I don't have any suggestions on how to do it (other than the general one of using shell and awk each to do what they do best), your questions and examples are always far too lengthy and complicated for me to have the time to try to understand them. I can't even tell what the awk code in your question is supposed to do, it's so convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary issue (repeated `text/text2` entries on stdout) comes from what appears to be a dual use of the `awk` variable `k` and some missing input control.

The `awk` variable `k` is being used as an auto-incremented index by the 2nd and 3rd `gsub(... k++ ...)` calls; at no point is `k` reset to `0` (or `1`) so logically speaking OPs `k==1` tests should only occur once.  However ...

The tests for `k==1` will occur for every input line (from all files) ... this occurs for lines with and without the `home_cool` string; and because there are two `k==1` tests being validated for each input line OP is going to get double outputs (`text` and `text2`) as long as `k==1`.

Also keep in mind that `k` is only being incremented (by the `gsub()` calls) for lines with the string `home_cool`; net result is lines without `home_cool` will see `k==1` unchanged so the two `k==1` tests will fire for these lines, too; we'll get extra `text/text2` entries on stdout until the next `gsub()` fires and increments `k` (via the `k++`)

---

I'd suggest using a different variable (eg, `p`) to determine when to print the `text/text2` entries, and moving the `k==1` tests (now `if (p)`) to a location where they are only run when appropriate.

One idea for a rewrite:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {++f; p=1}                                     # reset our "p"rintme? flag for each new file

f==1 {a[i++]=$0}

f==2 {if ($0~/home_cool/)
         {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(j++/2)%2]) }
      print > "2.txt"
     }

f==3 {if ($0~/home_cool/)
         {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2])}
      if (p)                                          # old "k==1" test; if "p"rintme flag set then ...
         {print "text"; system("sleep 4"); p=0}       # print, sleep, clear flag
      print > "3.txt"                            
     }

f==4 {if ($0~/home_cool/) 
         {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2])}
      if (p)                                          # old "k==1" test; if "p"rintme flag set then ...
         {print "text2"; system("sleep 4"); p=0}      # print, sleep, clear flag
      print > "4.txt"
     }
' 1.txt 0.txt 0-1.txt 0-2.txt
```

When run this generates the following on stdout:

```
text
text2
```

**NOTES:**

- other than the print issues I'm assuming OP's logic is correct (ie, the contents of the `[234].txt` files are correct)
- if an input file is empty then the associated `f==?` test will not fire which means ...
- the associated `if (p)...` test/operation will not fire;
- for example ...
- if `0-2.txt` is empty then `f==4` will never test as positive so ...
- the associated `if (p) ... print "text2" ...` will not fire
- it's not clear (to me) if OP needs to conditionally print the `text/text2` messages if the corresponding files are empty ...
- easy enough to modify the code but I'll skip that for now so as to limit the confusion

Comment: Really my question is just limited to the context of sources files presented and expected outputs, and at the moment is the only necessity. But ... I have not tested the Markp-fuso answer, and I believe it is more versatile to work on several other requirements in the future, but .. user Dan exactly presented the solution to my question. I have not had time to test the markp-fuso response, so I'll do the markp-fuso test of respect to the three authors of the responses respectively, before giving as resolved this issue. Thanks

Comment: fwiw ... the question asks: how to run `system()` call once `and echo 'text' is run only once`; that's all this answer is addressing

Comment: I did not say that I will analyze under the criterion of versatility, I said that although your answer seems to be more versatile, for all purposes, I have not even tested your answer yet, I just made an observation about the likely versatility of your answer, I will judge only on the criteria of the title of the question as you mentioned.

Comment: as for the title means that once since I was not able to print "text" a single time, If I add a new system () command that prints "text2" to the other file number is also expected to only print a single text2

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to add a command shell only one time run after creating the 2.txt file and before creating the 3.txt file.

Add a test for `FNR==1`, as the very first command of the `f==3` block, like so:

```
f==3 {if (FNR==1) {system("##")}; if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2]) }; print > "3.txt"}
```

It will be executed before anything else in that block.

Alternatively, you can add this `pattern {action}`, directly above `f==3`:

```
f==3 && FNR==1 {system("##")}
f==3 {if ($0~/home_cool/) {gsub(/home_cool/, a[int(k++/2)%3 + 2]) }; print > "3.txt"}
```

The pattern/action blocks are always executed in the order given, so again, it will execute first.

Whichever you think is more readable.

Comment: really my question is just limited to the context of sources files presented and expected outputs, and at the moment is the only necessity. But ... I have not tested the Markp-fuso answer, and I believe it is more versatile to work on several other requirements in the future, but .. user Dan exactly presented the solution to my question. I have not had time to test the markp-fuso response, so I'll do the markp-fuso test of respect to the three authors of the responses respectively, before giving as resolved this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to see what really misses to solve this and echo 'text'
> is run only once and before `2.txt` be created?

If you want following behavior: only run if `2.txt` does not exist then change

```
{system("echo 'text' && sleep 4")}
```

to

```
{system("ls 2.txt && echo 'text' && sleep 4")}
```

If there is not `2.txt` `ls` will malfunction and prevent execution of what is beyond `&&`. Note that `ls` does emit output, if this is not acceptable in your case you will need to add `stdout` and `stderr` redirections for `ls` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not listen to the stempiles not to specify that command shell should be run after the completion of the processing that generates `2.txt`. Because although `2.txt` has been created, it is still being processed and populated with `awk` substitutions. In this case I edited the question, thank you, I'm sorry for this mistake of my part.